# how to save node js consol log to .json file

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I want to save the output of node.js & console.log as a JSON file.

The first part is working fine but unable to save it on the file. I also tried to save through:

`$node filename.js > test.json`

It's working but it can't format files properly

```
var gplay = require('google-play-scraper');

const fs = require('fs')


function def() {
   gplay.app({appId: 'com.sablostudio.printing3d.town.builder', country: 'us'}).then(console.log) ;
}
def();


fs.writeFile('./newconstomer.json', JSON.stringify(--------???, null, 2), err => {

if (err) {
   console.log(err);
} else {
   console.log("file done");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `writeFile` in this way:

First, you need a logger function that takes the `log` and saves it to the `newconstomer.json` file:

```
function logger(log){
    fs.writeFile('./newconstomer.json', JSON.stringify(log), function (err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    console.log("file done");
  });
}
```

Now, replace the `console.log` method with the `logger` function:

```
function def() {
   gplay.app({appId: 'com.sablostudio.printing3d.town.builder', country: 'us'}).then( logger ) ; // <--- place the logger function here
}
def();
```

##### Explanation:

The `logger` function takes a `log` parameter and parsed it by `JSON.stringify()` method.